# [Protractor]: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 121.0.6167.139

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to run end-to-end testing using **Protractor** having chrome version `121.0.6167.139`, for this I have done following steps:

1. `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=114.0.5735.198`
2. `webdriver-manager start`
3. Write `protractor.conf.js` file:

   ```
   exports.config = {
    specs: ['src/app/component/testcases/counterbutton.component.e2e-spec.ts'],

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/'
   };
   ```
4. Run following command to start test: `protractor protractor.conf.js`

But getting an **error**:

```
[17:10:11] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:10:11] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[17:10:12] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 121.0.6167.139 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
```

How can I run this test with my updated chrome version ?

Comment: I don't understand. The error states you have a mismatch between chrome (v121) and chromedriver (114). And this is what you seem to be doing intentionally by installing driver 114